# Why is this seq_file misc char driver freezing my system?

Tags: linux, char, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I'm learning how to write Linux device drivers, and am at the moment stumped with a very simple example of a misc char device. I have this:

```
static char *dev_contents = "hello world!";

static int demo_show(struct seq_file *f, void *unused)
{
        seq_puts(f, dev_contents);
        return 0;
}

static int demo_open(struct inode *i, struct file *f)
{
        return single_open(f, demo_show, NULL);
}

const struct file_operations demo_fops = {
        .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
        .open   = demo_open,
        .read   = seq_read,
        .llseek = seq_lseek,
        .release = single_release,
};

static struct miscdevice demo_dev = {
        MISC_DYNAMIC_MINOR,
        "demo",
        &demo_fops
};

int __init init_module(void)
{
        int res = 0;

        res = misc_register(&demo_dev);
        if (res)
                pr_err("Error registering demo misc device.\n");

        return res;
}

void __exit cleanup_module(void)
{
        misc_deregister(&demo_dev);
}
```

It does show up in /dev as expected, and I can cat the device file. The string is returned, but the whole system freezes after the last character is returned.

I've compared this to other examples that do the same thing, and I'm having trouble seeing what I've done wrong. Anyone care to point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try this using a newline at the end of the string?

Comment: as Peter said try using `seq_putc(f, '\n');`

Comment: I just tried that, and though I do see the newline when I view the file the system still freezes after that. Thanks anyway!